# What are the exceptional properties of Mersenne exponent for known largest prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

It is a clear that largest known primes are Mersenne prime. It is well known that $2^p - 1$ is prime only if $p$ is prime; however, the converse is not true - take $p = 11$. My question is: is there some nontrivial characterization of which primes $p$ have the property that $2^p - 1$ is prime? I think from GIMP theorist up to some exceptional properties .

**Note**: Actually I find this property "The only exponent of known largest prime equal to $3 \bmod 11$ is $77232917$

Comment: I've edited your question for grammar. I think I've preserved the idea of the question; however, if you think otherwise, please feel free to revert the edit. I left the last sentence of the paragraph as-is because I couldn't figure out what you were trying to say.

Comment: @Thanks so much with your edit and for Martin Slezial edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primes $p$ such that $2^p-1$ is prime are called *Mersenne exponents*. You can find many of their properties on the corresponding entry of the OEIS, namely [A000043](https://oeis.org/A000043). Beyond their obvious connections with perfect numbers, there are also characterisations like

> The (prime) number $p$ appears in this sequence if and only if there is no prime $q<2^p-1$ such that the order of $2$ modulo $q$ equals $p$.

As a particular case of this, we have

> If $p=4k+3$ is prime and also $q=2p+1$ is prime then the order of $2$ modulo $q$ is $p$, so $p$ is not a term of this sequence.

There is also the following characterisation.

> $p$ is a Mersenne exponent if and only if every degree $p$ irreducible polynomial over GF(2) is also primitive (i.e. has order $2^p-1$).

Some of the properties you'll find on the OEIS are often quite quick to prove.